# How to implement surrogate key in place of composite natural key in database form

Tags: database, forms, database-design

Suppose an automatically generated ID is used as follows as the `device` table's primary key instead of the natural combination of model and serial number.

```
id    model   sn     detail      
---------------------------
1     A       01     blah
2     A       02
3     B       01
```

Now in order to relate another table to `device`, how do you design a form for data entry so that the user can select a device in a natural way? That is to say, choose the model in a combo box, then choose the SN in the next combo box, which shows only the serial numbers from the chosen model as options.

If the first combobox is unbound, then the model won't show when you return to the form for review. If the the first combobox is bound to `model` (or more realistically `model_id`) and the second to `id` (while showing `sn` in the combobox for the user to select), then the first is completely superfluous and thus probably violates a normal form. If the first is bound to `model` and the second to `sn`, then we're just using composite natural keys and might as well get rid of the surrogate key altogether.

I've done this before using natural keys and it worked well. But since surrogate keys seem to be favored, I wonder how it would be done given that design choice.

Answer (score 2):

From the user standpoint, having the first bound to `model` and the second bound to `sn` is the most intuitive and realistically the only viable option. Say I have the device with `model: B; sn: 01`. I am going to have no way of knowing that my device is also `id: 3` unless there is some sticker designating it as `id: 3` or I was notified that `3` was the devices number. But the `model` and `sn` are always going to be placed on the device by the manufacturer.

From the database standpoint, either key works. Both the keys `(id)` and `(model, sn)` uniquely identify the device. Having `id` is superfluous, true, but it can be used in related tables as a table constraint to reduce total DB size (serial numbers can be large and will need to be a variant of `CHAR`) and simplify joined queries.

IMO, have both. Use the key `(model, sn)` whenever a user is involved and use `(id)` for joining all related tables together.

Comment: +1 Also, foreign keys become tricky if you don't have the `id`. Imagine you wanted to store when a device gets serviced, you would have to add both a model and a sn to your services table...

Comment: From your answer, it appears my original question (since edited) was unclear. There was never a question of requiring the user to know the `id`. Even when the second combobox is bound to `id` (bound column), the visible column will be from the more user-friendly `sn`. So that would be workable, except the `model` column would be superfluous in that scenario.

Comment: I would love to use `id` to join instead of `(model, sn)`, but how is that going to work when data entry here is always done by human users and all the relations created through user-friendly forms will always be based on `(model, sn)`. To take the example from @Pevara, the technician who logs the service case will ideally use a form that asks for model and then sn.